# Is it correct to pass model reference directly to HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model

Is it correct to pass model reference directly to HTML element?

```
window.car = {
   color: "blue",
   maxSpeed: 200
 }
var element = $("<div>");
car.$element = element;
element[0]._model = car;
```

$("") creates a new jQuery element. JQuery has wrapped elements saved inside in keys 0,1,2 ... so [0] return first wrapped HTMLelement. _model is only name of reference variable.

Comment: I guess spelling of widow is wrong. please check your code.

Comment: How come an MVC model maps to javascript? Isn't the model on server-side?

Comment: I'd tried to keep clear idea. Origin of model is irrelevant. It is client-side script.

Comment: what `element[0]._model = car;` should do? Where does `_model` come from? what's the desired effect of this statement?

Comment: Adding expando properties directly to DOM elements creates a circular reference and can lead to memory leaks especially in IE. It's generally a good idea to avoid this.

Answer (score 6):

Use [jQuery's `data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for that. Adding new properties directly to DOM nodes may run into problems and is considered harmful.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could attach the object to a `data-model` attribute instead of attaching it directly as a dom node property (it could be destructive), just using

```
$(element[0]).data('model', car);
```